# custom pager in jquery bxslider plugin

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm having an issue with jQuery and I don't really know where to start.

Basically I am using the [bxslider plugin](http://bxslider.com/) to make a carousel.

Here is simplified HTML:

```
<ul id="promos">
    <li>
        <h2>Event Title 1</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Event Title 2</h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the jquery :

```
$('ul#promos').after('<div id="pager1"></div>');
$('ul#promos').bxSlider({
    displaySlideQty: 1,
    moveSlideQty: 1,
    infiniteLoop: false,
    controls: false, 
    pager: true,
    pagerSelector: '#pager1',
    auto: true,
    pause: 5000,
    speed: 1000
});
```

This renders the output as:

```
<ul id="promos">
    <li>
        <h2>Event Title 1</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Event Title 2</h2>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="pager1">
    <a href="" class="pager-link pager-1 pager-active">1</a>
    <a href="" class="pager-link pager-2">2</a>
</div>
```

However, I want the pager to use the relative h2 titles, rather then ascending numbers. So ideally it would look like:

```
<div id="pager1">
    <a href="" class="pager-link pager-1 pager-active">Event Title 1</a>
    <a href="" class="pager-link pager-2">Event Title 2</a>
</div>
```

Note: there can be up to six events in this carousel.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjacob/gHpBT/3/

Any pointers where to start would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out using an example on http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-2

The example uses "buildPager:" replaces the standard 1,2,3,4 pager with images, the example:

```
$(function(){
  $('#slider1').bxSlider({
    pager: true,
    buildPager: function(slideIndex){
      switch (slideIndex){
        case 0:
          return '<a href=""><img src="/sites/all/themes/bx/images/pic_velvet1_thumb.jpg" /></a>';
        case 1:
          return '<a href=""><img src="/sites/all/themes/bx/images/pic_velvet2_thumb.jpg" /></a>';
        case 2:
          return '<a href=""><img src="/sites/all/themes/bx/images/pic_velvet3_thumb.jpg" /></a>';
        case 3:
          return '<a href=""><img src="/sites/all/themes/bx/images/pic_velvet4_thumb.jpg" /></a>';
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to target the active state of the pager to source a different image?

Answer (score 1):

I just built my own pager using the bxSlider callbacks and public methods.

I'm using haml and coffeescript, but you should get the idea.

I'm using a data-id attribute on the custom pager links to tie that link to a particular slide

HAML

```
%ul.landing-links
  %li <a href="#" data-id="0" class="active">Slide One</a>
  %li <a href="#" data-id="1">Slide Two</a>
```

CoffeeScript

```
landing_slides = $("#landing-slides").bxSlider
  controls: false,
  auto: true,
  pause: 10000,
  autoHover: true,
  onAfterSlide: (num, qty, obj) ->
    # Switch the active class to the corresponding pager link
    $("ul.landing-links li a.active").removeClass("active")
    $("ul.landing-links li a[data-id=#{num}]").addClass("active")

$('ul.landing-links li a').click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  landing_slides.goToSlide($(this).data('id')) # Get the data-id attribute value
  landing_slides.startShow() # This is needed to restart the auto scroll
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the below html code for pagination

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){        
  jQuery('#bxslider1').bxSlider({
    pagerCustom: '#bxsliderlist1'
  });   
});
```

```html
<ul id="bxslider1">
  <li>
    your contant
  </li>
  <li>
    your contant
  </li>
  <li>
    your contant
  </li>
  <li>
    your contant
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="bxsliderlist1">
  <li>
    <a data-slide-index="0">your contant</a>
  </li>
   <li>
    <a data-slide-index="1">your contant</a>
  </li>
   <li>
    <a data-slide-index="2">your contant</a>
  </li>
   <li>
    <a data-slide-index="3">your contant</a>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```